# How to delete a directory from a master branch in BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

so I'm a noob at using Git and all it's functionalities.

Yesterday I tried to push a .gitignore file on my master branch in BitBucket and somehow I managed to push it within two directories. So, now, my master looks like dir1/dir2/.gitignore

I've tried deleting the dir1 like so

```
git checkout master
git rm -r --cached dir1
fatal: pathspec 'dir1' did not match any files
```

This is the error I'm getting. What to do?

Comment: Git doesn't do "directories". Remove the stuff _in_ the directory. — Actually in this case I don't understand why you don't just move the `.gitignore` file to where you want it, then add and commit that change.

Comment: are you sure you pushed it to the remote repo. What you wrote should remove it from the remote location only, if its there. Either its not there or you have the wrong spelling. verify on the git repo its there.